# "Parking" a div with jquery Waypoints.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I've created a div that becomes fixed as expected. However later on down the page I want it to become "parked" once scrolling reaches a specific div. Can this be accomplished?

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="topper"></div>
    <div class="margins">This is .margins
        <div class="container"> This is .container
            <div class="waypoint">.waypoint - gets .stuck</div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="stophere">How can I make .waypoint park here until I scroll back up?</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.stophere').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('.waypoint').waypoint('unsticky');
});
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/f3YZ2/62/) where I've been trying things for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$('.waypoint').waypoint('unsticky');` add a class to your waypoint item. Style that class as needed to place it where you want. The exact styling you need will depend on your page, so I cannot provide more detail.

Comment: You need to know the waypoint's current position to *park* it. The dynamic position cannot be set by a CSS class, only via JavaScript. Also, how about *unparking* (removing the absolute positioning and going back to fixed) when scrolling up again? The waypoint event does not get triggered because the wrapper became the waypoint, so where should one attach the *unparking* statements to?